# Probability question involving colored balls

Tags: probability

Probability question.  I’ve been trying to figure this out for a while and need a little help.  This is not a homework problem just something I made up but can’t figure it out on my own.

I have a total of 30 balls(10 red, 10 green, 10 blue) I dump all 30 balls into a large bin.

I have 4 smaller containers.  I randomly take 2 balls out and put them in each of the 4 smaller containers (I remove 8 balls total).  What are my chances of having 2 bins or more of just red balls?  Can you please show the math behind the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be the event of interest ( at least 2 bins have 2 red balls). Let $R$ be the amount of red balls extracted (out of 8). Then

$$ P(E) = \sum_{R=0}^8 P(E \mid R) P(R)$$

Now,

$$P(R)= \frac{\binom{10}{R} \binom{20}{8-R}}{\binom{30}{8}}$$

And $P(E \mid R)=0$ for $R\le 3$ and $P(E \mid R)=1$ for $R\ge 6$.

You need only to compute $P(E \mid R=4)$ and $(E \mid R=5)$... can you go on from here?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle) strategy:

Call the bins A,B,C,D, and let AB represent the event that both A and B are all red (with no requirements on the other bins); ABC the event that A,B,C are all red (with no requirements on D); etc.

First, let's find P(AB). The order in which we fill the bins doesn't matter - we might as well have put the first four removed balls into bins A and B, and the probability these are all red is $\frac{10}{30}\frac{9}{29}\frac{8}{28}\frac{7}{27}$. The same goes for any other pair of bins, so P(AB)+P(AC)+P(AD)+P(BC)+P(BD)+P(CD) $= 6P(AB) =6\cdot\frac{10}{30}\frac{9}{29}\frac{8}{28}\frac{7}{27}$.

This sum does some over-counting. Any outcome where *exactly* two bins are all red falls into just one of the six cases, so we've counted it correctly, but any outcome in which *three* bins are all red appears in three of the two-bin events (e.g. ABC is counted in each of AB,AC,BC), so by adding the six probabilities, we've over-counted these outcomes by a factor of 3. Let's correct that by un-counting them twice, by subtracting 2(P(ABC)+P(ABD)+P(ACD)+P(BCD)) $=2\cdot 4\cdot P(ABC)=8 \cdot \frac{10}{30}\frac{9}{29}\frac{8}{28}\frac{7}{27}\frac{6}{26}\frac{5}{25}$ (because P(ABC) equals the probability that the first six balls we look at are all red).

Now our adjusted sum correctly accounts for the exactly-two-bin and exactly-three-bin outcomes, and we just need to fix it for ABCD, which was "accidentally" included in *all* the events considered above. We added its probability 6 times and subtracted it 8 times, so we should add it back 3 times to get its count back to 1.

So the probability that at least two bins are all red is
$$6\cdot\frac{10}{30}\frac{9}{29}\frac{8}{28}\frac{7}{27}-8\cdot \frac{10}{30}\frac{9}{29}\frac{8}{28}\frac{7}{27}\frac{6}{26}\frac{5}{25}+3\cdot \frac{10}{30}\frac{9}{29}\frac{8}{28}\frac{7}{27}\frac{6}{26}\frac{5}{25}\frac{4}{24}\frac{3}{23}.$$